# Sign SSL certificate using CA

Tags: java, ssl, certificate

I need to sign a certificate using a CA but can't figure out how to do it. The system we work with basically has a client and a server. The server has access to the CA required to sign the client's certificate. When the client needs an updated certificate it will generate a keypair and send the public key to the server. After this, the server will sign the public key into a certificate using the CA and send it back so the client can use it to establish future connections.

The problem I'm running into is that I can't find a way to sign the new certificate. I have tried using the `KeyPairGenerator` class and the `CertAndKeyGen` class but everything is just too vague to figure it out.

Here is what I have right now:

```
        CertAndKeyGen cert = new CertAndKeyGen("RSA", "SHA1WithRSA", "");
        cert.generate(2048);

        Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("RSA", "SUN");
        PKCS10 pkcs10 = cert.getCertRequest(new X500Name("AME"));
        pkcs10.encodeAndSign(new X500Name("AME"), dsa);
```

The code doesn't include the CA though. Is there any way to sign it using the CA?

Comment: Java doesn't support this, but I believe the Bouncy Castle JCE provider does.

Comment: @user207421 can you give me an example? I have tried some bouncy castle implementations but I noticed its very high level stuff and couldn't really do much with it without hours of searching